# How to get wlan transfer speed?

Tags: c#, c++, wlanapi

How to get current value of wlan transfer speed(PC-Router)? I am trying to search this parametr in wlanapi library, but I couldn't.

I want "wireless network connection speed". I guess it is the same as "theoretical bits per second"

Comment: Find a function that provides statistics (total bytes sent/received) and call it every second.

Comment: Do you want "bytes per second actually transferred" or the "theoretical bits per second"? The two can be very different, and the approach to "get" either is definitely not the same.

Comment: I want "wireless network connection speed". I guess it is the same as "theoretical bits per second"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want "wireless network connection speed". I guess it is the same as "theoretical bits per second"

You can get it like this:

```
var speed = NetworkInterface.GetAllNetworkInterfaces()
            .Where(inf => inf.NetworkInterfaceType == NetworkInterfaceType.Wireless80211)
            .Where(inf => inf.OperationalStatus == OperationalStatus.Up)
            .Select(inf => inf.Speed)
            .First();
```